# Where n the website can I find my Clickatell API ID?

Tags: clickatell

It seems to be non existent on the Clickatell website -- just the API Key - but that's not what's expected according to the API's response...

Clickatell are not seeming to be consistant. Anyone know the answer to this?

Cheers,
M.

Comment: Hmm. I was going to point you to Clickatell's website. But their [Ask The Community](https://www.clickatell.com/contact/ask-the-community/) page redirects to here. How cheap...

Comment: I rest my case!

Answer (score 0):

I see it as soon as I log in, but note I use central/communicator. If you're a platform customer your mileage may vary. See highlight below:

[image]

Comment: I am a platform customer -- which presumably means I'm not allowed to send texts -- How's that for a Texting service!!!

Comment: Thanks for the detail though - M.